# Why mysql_secure_installation isn't working?

Tags: mysql, installation, mariadb

I tried to find answers but none of them is working. I installed mariadb on centos7 Linux. Then I try to run `mysql_secure_installation` and received error: command not found. The problem is that I already did it one time and it worked and I tried to do it few days later it isn't working. What should I do?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Confirm if mariadb is still running on the server. If it's a remote server, confirm you're on the right server.

Comment: I am trying to build a web page using apache-mariadb-php . I am installing mariadb and mariadb-server starting it enableing it then i try to do mysql_secure_installation later I need an access to phpmyadmin using mariadb password....that's it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It appears you forgot your password and want to use it to access your database through phpmyadmin, follow the instruction in this link to reset your password https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 1):

Try:

mariadb-secure-installation

Comment: From 10.5.2, mysql_secure_installation was changed to a symlink to the mariadb-secure-installation binary. But I've just tried in 10.11 and the symlink doesn't appear to be work anymore